# SPI SDHC Initialization Timing Problems

Tags: arduino, sd

I Have a 16GB Wi-Fi SD HC Card from Transcend.
I try to initialize the card via SPI using an Arduino Uno, sending

> CMD0, arg: 0         , CRC: 0x95
>
> response:0xFF

but the expected response is:

> 0x01

When i try the same process with an 2 GB SD (no SDHC) card, the response is:

> 0x01

as expected. So the initialization process itself can't be the problem.

Here you can see the Timings of the 2GB SD card analyzed with a logic analyzer:
[image: Logic Analysis 1]

Here you can see the Timings of the SDHC card analyzed by a logic analyzer:
[image: Logic Analysis]

The strange thing about it is, the SD card acts as expected using:

> Mode 0 (CPHA=0,CPOL=0)

So the MISO value is always stable at the **rising** edge as i expected it to be: ([Using MMC/SDC](http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html))

On the other hand, the SDHC card doesn't behave like this, and this might be the reason why the initialization process fails. The SDHC card seems to work in Mode 1 , so the MISO value is always stable at the **falling** edge.

Why is the SDHC card not running in mode 0, as I expect it too?

**Update:**
I am using the [sdfatlib](https://github.com/frasermac/sdfatlib) which is waiting the required 74 clock cycles.

> // must supply min of 74 clock cycles with CS high.
>
> for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) spiSend(0XFF);

And also the recorded behavior shows that there are more than 74 clock cycles until CS is set to low to send the init command.

> Pulses: 79 ( up: 79, down: 80)
> [image]

Comment: An SDHC Card can take up to 8 bytes (64 SPI clock cycles) before returning a response.  Try Sending 0xFF for at least 8 bytes and see if the SDHC ever gives a response.

Comment: Actually I guess it is giving a response, since it is pulling it's line down after the first byte.  Hmm...

Comment: Do you give the card enough startup cycles on the clock line? The standard is quite clear on this and larger card will often misbehave if they don't have time to initialise after power on.

Comment: My [rough code](https://github.com/edeca/Electronics/blob/master/Include/sd_spi.c) which tries to follow the spec has a comment about 74 clock cycles. I don't have the standards document to hand to look it up.